# Sidebar 'jumping' in mobile

Tags: css

I have a sidebar that is functionally similar to the one from w3schools, and the sidebar from w3schools displays the same problem. The sidebar 'jumps' and leaves an unsightly space in the area, when scrolling down the page and mobile chrome's navbar hides, it leaves a hole at the top, and when scrolling up and the menu slides back out, it covers the top, and makes a space at the bottom.

This is my sidebar's state when I first started testing for mobile (which I forgot)

```
.sidenav {
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -250px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    transition: var(--delay);
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none !important;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #999999, #999999 95%, #000000 95%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, #999999, #999999 95%, #000000 95%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, #999999, #999999 95%, #000000 95%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #999999, #999999 95%, #000000 95%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 100%);
}
```

The main difference between my sidebar and w3's is that it's meant to be scrollable since I will fill it with a few links. Now, considering that w3's has the same error as mine, I know for a fact that it isn't caused by the additional content that is placed on the sidebar.

Through testing and research, I have found that the viewport of mobile (and the hiding of chrome's menu) is the one that's actually causing the issue, along with bottom, with the browser being unable to update 'top' and 'bottom' to 0.

I tried to fix this in multiple ways:

1. Removing Bottom

Which just ended up creating a space where the navigation links/content ends

2. Making Height 100%

Which just made it unscrollable when the expandable divs open and destroying desktop functionality

3. The current solution

Which allows the desktop version to work as fully intended, fixes the 'space' or 'jumping' issue, but also makes it so that on mobile it can't scroll all the way down.

```
.sidenav {
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -250px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    transition: var(--delay);
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none !important;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #999999, #999999 95%, #000000 95%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, #999999, #999999 95%, #000000 95%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, #999999, #999999 95%, #000000 95%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #999999, #999999 95%, #000000 95%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 100%);
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .sidenav {
        bottom: 0;
        height: initial;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>`
 in the `<head>` of your html document and see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help. All that achieved was making the mobile version zoomed in and unable to zoom out